# Using GRPC Gem on M1 Mac _gpr_asprintf issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, grpc, apple-m1

I'm currently trying to run `rake db:migrate` on my new m1 mbp after my gems have been successfully installed.

Upon running this I run into:

```
jasondorn@Jasons-MacBook-Pro-2 Homebase1 % rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/jasondorn/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.42.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_gpr_asprintf' - /Users/jasondorn/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.42.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c.bundle
/Users/jasondorn/Developer/Homebase1/config/application.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jasondorn/Developer/Homebase1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
jasondorn@Jasons-MacBook-Pro-2 Homebase1 % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [-darwin21]
jasondorn@Jasons-MacBook-Pro-2 Homebase1 % rbenv -v
rbenv 1.2.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpEbo.png)

macOS 12.0.1 (21A559) Monterey

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could manage to build the gem (version 1.43.0) using Ruby 2.7.5. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/28509
my gemfile now looks like this:

`gem('grpc', github: 'grpc/grpc', tag: 'v1.43.0', submodules: true)`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30808411)

Comment: if you check the PO error message, you will see this "symbol not found in flat namespace '_gpr_asprintf'" and it's because of it's GRPC gem and it's ruby version.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah my hope was to get things working on 2.6.5, but I wasn't able to. Upgrading ruby to 2.7.x was the only way i could get things working

Comment: I hit this too, my grpc was already at 1.57. Ruby was at 2.6.6. Upgrading to ruby 2.6.7 solved this for me.